# Notebook based on jupyter/all-spark-notebook docker image not picking up custom python version

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

## Summary

I am trying to execute [this simple python code snippet](https://github.com/kevinsuedmersen/hadoop-sandbox/blob/e0a061dd3a60842aa0e93893892c7e0844c2278a/jupyter-spark/work/tests/simple_cluster.ipynb) in an all-spark-notebook which is supposed to be executed in a local spark cluster which I setup in [this docker-compose file](https://github.com/kevinsuedmersen/hadoop-sandbox/blob/e0a061dd3a60842aa0e93893892c7e0844c2278a/docker-compose.yml). However, I am getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'` which doesn't make sense to me, because in [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/kevinsuedmersen/hadoop-sandbox/blob/e0a061dd3a60842aa0e93893892c7e0844c2278a/jupyter-spark/Dockerfile) (which I took from the [docker repos documentation](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/recipes.html#add-a-python-3-x-environment)) I explicitly installed pyspark with pip.

## Steps to reproduce the error

```
# Clone the repository and checkout a specific commit
kevinsuedmersen@LAPTOP-XXX:~/dev/hadoop-sandbox$ git clone https://github.com/kevinsuedmersen/hadoop-sandbox.git
kevinsuedmersen@LAPTOP-XXX:~/dev/hadoop-sandbox$ git checkout e0a061dd3a60842aa0e93893892c7e0844c2278a

# Install and start all services
kevinsuedmersen@LAPTOP-XXX:~/dev/hadoop-sandbox$ docker-compose up -d

# Entering the container running the notebooks
kevinsuedmersen@LAPTOP-XXX:~/dev/hadoop-sandbox$ docker exec -it jupyter-spark bash

# Activating the custom python environment installed in the above referenced Dockerfile
(base) jovyan@XXX:~$ conda activate python37

# Start a jupyter notebook server
(python37) jovyan@XXX:~$ jupyter notebook

# After some logging, the following output shows
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-27913-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://b8ef36545270:8889/?token=some_token
or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=some_token
```

Then, I click on the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=some_token` to open up the jupyter GUI in my browser, execute [the simple python code snippet](https://github.com/kevinsuedmersen/hadoop-sandbox/blob/e0a061dd3a60842aa0e93893892c7e0844c2278a/jupyter-spark/work/tests/simple_cluster.ipynb) and get the above error as explained above.

## What I've tried

To check if pyspark was really installed, I basically just tried to execute [the simple python code snippet](https://github.com/kevinsuedmersen/hadoop-sandbox/blob/e0a061dd3a60842aa0e93893892c7e0844c2278a/jupyter-spark/work/tests/simple_cluster.ipynb) in the shell of the jupyter-spark container and surprisingly, it worked. Specifically, I executed the following commands in a new shell:

```
# Entering into the jupyter-spark container and activating the custom python environment
kevinsuedmersen@LAPTOP-XXX:~/dev/hadoop-sandbox$ docker exec -it jupyter-spark bash
(base) jovyan@XXX:~$ conda activate python37

# Opening a python shell
(python37) jovyan@XXX:~$ python

# Copy pasting the same commands from the notebook into the shell
>>> import pyspark
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.master('spark://spark-master:7077').getOrCreate()
>>> sc = spark.sparkContext
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(range(100 + 1))
>>> rdd.sum()
5050
```

Furthermore, I noticed that executing the following in the notebook

```
! python --version
```

prints `Python 3.8.8`

So, my question is: *How can I make the notebook use the custom python environment*?

Answer (score 1):

So, apparantly, the following workaround works:

1. Change the Dockerfile of the jupyter-spark service to something as simple as:

```
FROM jupyter/all-spark-notebook:584f43f06586

ARG SPARK_VERSION
ARG HADOOP_VERSION
ARG SPARK_CHECKSUM
ARG OPENJDK_VERSION
ARG PYTHON_VERSION

# Install a different version of python inside the base environment
RUN conda install -y python=$PYTHON_VERSION

# Install required pip packages, e.g. pyspark
COPY requirements.txt /docker_build/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /docker_build/requirements.txt
```

2. The service definition in the `docker-compose.yml` file becomes:

```
# Spark notebooks
  jupyter-spark:
    # To see all running servers in this container, execute 
    # `docker exec jupyter-spark jupyter notebook list`
    container_name: jupyter-spark
    build:
      context: jupyter-spark
      args: 
        - SPARK_VERSION=3.1.1
        - HADOOP_VERSION=3.2
        - SPARK_CHECKSUM=E90B31E58F6D95A42900BA4D288261D71F6C19FA39C1CB71862B792D1B5564941A320227F6AB0E09D946F16B8C1969ED2DEA2A369EC8F9D2D7099189234DE1BE
        - OPENJDK_VERSION=11
        # Make sure the python version in the driver (the notebooks) is the same as in spark-master,
        # spark-worker-1, and spark-worker-2
        - PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.10
    ports: 
      - 8888:8888
      - 8889:8889
      - 4040:4040
      - 4041:4041
    volumes:
      - ./jupyter-spark/work:/home/jovyan/work
    pid: host
    environment: 
      - TINI_SUBREAPER=true
    env_file: 
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop
```

The currently working state of the repository with the above changes can be [here](https://github.com/kevinsuedmersen/hadoop-sandbox/tree/e6818668d3059eb143ec34c161877267c94aed53)